# Location of macros in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, macros

I would like to edit a recorded Macro but I could not find the location.

Where the macro (I guess macro.xml) is located ?

I'm using IntelliJ 2019.3 CE

Comment: You should vote for this issue for proper macro edit support: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92246

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is located in [IDE configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory)/options/macros.xml.

But why do you need to edit an xml file manually? You can edit [macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) using Main Menu: Edit | Macros | **Edit Macros** action.

Comment: Have you actually tried using the Edit Macros feature? It's almost useless. The only thing you can do is rename the macro and remove actions. You can't manually add actions or text input, or modify the existing entries. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92246 - go vote for proper macro support... lol